# Echo statement and time /t on the same line

Tags: date, batch-file

How would I display the following in Batch?:

```
It is currently 01:58 AM
```

I have tried `echo It is currently && time /t` but it displays

```
It is currently
01:58 AM
```

Comment: or a very general but hacky solution: `<nul set/p"=It is currently "&time/t`

Comment: What about using the pseudo-variable `%TIME%`: `echo It is currently %TIME%`...

Comment: @HackingAddict1337, I'd say it's worth mentioning that your `set /P` approach sets the `ErrorLevel` value...

Comment: @aschipfl it's also worth mentioning that `time /t` sets `ERRORLEVEL` as well. this can be avoided using `echo %time%`, but may not be what the OP wants in this case.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this :

```
@echo off
FOR /F "tokens=1,2" %%A IN ('time /t') DO Echo It is currently %%A %%B
```

For more info [Link](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html).